# Firebase Hosting, how to deploy the same code on more account at once

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is there a way to upload a folder with some files into different accounts on firebase hosting simultaneously?
I need this to be able to update the same app on different firebase accounts without the need to do it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command to deploy to multiple projects on multiple accounts. You will have to call `firebase deploy` separately for each project.

You may be able to automate the process though, by [using the CLI as it'd be done in CI systems](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems).

Comment: .I though could be possible to creare a function that could accept an array of files and write them on the same hosting space, in this way I could sent the same array of files or gzipped on each account the get the result I need. Could it be possible

Comment: It seems possible, but you'll have to write the code to do the account switching and run the deploy command again for each account.